# Play2: How to overwrite config values within an unit test?

Tags: playframework

I've the following test code where I want to test if given configuration parameters are used when creating an object within the tested code. To accomplish this, I try to override the config parameter in the beginning, capture the object and assert if the fields are set correctly.

Unfortunately, the config parameters from application.conf will not be overwritten with my test values. What is wrong? How can I overwrite the config parameter for the test?

application.conf:

```
email.default_from_address="my@company.com"
email.default_from_name="MyCompany"
```

Test:

```
  @Test
  public void testReadFromConfig() throws IOException, MandrillApiError {
    final Map<String, String> testConfig = new HashMap<>();
    final String fromName = "UnitTest From";
    final String fromEmail = "from@unittest.com";
    testConfig.put("email.default_from_name", fromName);
    testConfig.put("email.default_from_address", fromEmail);
    testConfig.putAll(inMemoryDatabase());

    running(fakeApplication(testConfig), () -> {
      MandrillEmailService emailService = new MandrillEmailService(
          mockedMandrillApi);
      EmailMessage testMessage = createTestMessageHelper(
          EmailMessage.CONTENT_TYPE.TEXT_HTML);
      emailService.send(testMessage);
    });

    ArgumentCaptor<MandrillMessage> captorForMandrillMsg =
        ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MandrillMessage.class);
    verify(mockedMessagesApi).send(captorForMandrillMsg.capture(), eq(false));

    MandrillMessage capturedMandrillMsg = captorForMandrillMsg.getValue();
    assertEquals(fromName, capturedMandrillMsg.getFromName());
    assertEquals(fromEmail, capturedMandrillMsg.getFromEmail());
  }
```

Error:

```
failed: expected:<[UnitTest From]> but was:<[MyCompany]>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found overwriting config in `Play` test framework extremely difficult. It must be `Play` bug. If you are not familiar with `GlobalSettings` class here is a [resource](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaGlobal). Try overwriting one of `onLoadConfig` methods as follows:

```
@Override
public Configuration onLoadConfig(Configuration config, File path, ClassLoader classloader) {
    if(Play.isTest()){
         // load test configuration and overwrite properties programmatically.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My failure. The code mentioned above works. The problem was that I've read the configuration in a static block...

```
public class MandrillEmailService implements EmailService {

  private final static String FROM_ADDRESS;
  private final static String FROM_NAME;
  private final MandrillApi mandrillApi;

  static {
    FROM_ADDRESS = Play.application().configuration()
            .getString("email.default_from_address");
    FROM_NAME = Play.application().configuration()
            .getString("email.default_from_name");
  }

...
```